# WPF DataBinding to Path with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this `Path`

```
<Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
      <PathFigureCollection>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="20, 130">
          <PathFigure.Segments>
            <LineSegment Point="40, 4"/>
            <LineSegment Point="60, 132"/>
          </PathFigure.Segments>
        </PathFigure>
      </PathFigureCollection>
    </PathGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
```

I was told that it can be "stored" with

```
<Nums Color="Blue" Thick="2" SegmentWidth="20">
  <Sample Val="130" />
  <Sample Val="4" />
  <Sample Val="132" />
</Nums>
```

in some `ItemSource`.
It looks like truth because coords are `(SegmentWidth,y_1), (SegmentWidth*2,y_2), ..., (SegmentWidth*n,y_n)`.

But I don't know how to make `DataTemplate` for this `Path`. I was told that it should be done without "code behind".

If it's easier to achieve with Polyline rather than Path, it'll still be good. My only goal is transform XML (second code block) to polyline-like figure with coords `(SegmentWidth, Sample Val 1),..., (SegmentWidth * n, Sample Val n)`.